# R - Getting warnings: "only the first element is used as variable name"

Tags: r, function, warnings, assign

I'm trying to use "assign" function, inside a for loop, to assign the value of a file to one variable.

When I call the function, it brings the correct answer but in the end it gives me the following warning messages:

```
 In assign(fileList, read.csv(fileList[i])) :
 only the first element is used as variable name
```

If I run > corr("specdata", 129) I can see the correct answer, it can print all the right values, but If I assign the values to any variable for example, it says that this variable is "NULL". An example:

```
cr <- corr("specdata", 150) 
head(cr)
NULL
```

It will give me all the values that fit in this criteria but it seems that it can't pass the values to "cr". Other examples:

```
> class(cr)
[1] "NULL"
> cr
NULL
```

The code that I'm currently using, if is helpful:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold){
    if (directory == "specdata"){ 
        setwd("C:/Users/User/Downloads/specdata")

        fileList <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
        for (i in 1:length(fileList)){
            fileValues <- assign(fileList, read.csv(fileList[i]))
            okValues <- na.omit(fileValues)
            completeCases <- sum(complete.cases(okValues))
            if (completeCases > threshold) {
                sulfate <- okValues["sulfate"]
                nitrate <- okValues["nitrate"]
                correlation <- cor(sulfate, nitrate,  use="complete.obs", method=c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman")) 
                #print(correlation)

            }

            else if (completeCases <= threshold){
                #print("0")
            }

            i = i+1
        }
    }

    else {
        print("There's no such directory")
    }

}
```

I'm a begginer on R language, so, if there's any way to fix this issue or to read every single file from a folder and manipulate separately, I'd be glad.

Comment: That's not how `assign` works. It's used when you want to add arguments to `<-`. I suspect you just want `fileValues <- read.csv(fileList[i])`.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll That is indeed the problem.  `assign` happens to (invisibly) return the assigned value, which is why the code works at all.  It is having an unneeded side-effect of creating an object that is not subsequently used.  You should add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`assign` is used to do just that, "assign" a value to a variable ([up to semantics](http://bragqut.github.io/2016/05/26/milesmcbain-rnoprimitives/)). I suspect you want

```
fileValues <- read.csv(fileList[i])
```

Comment: Thank you, the simplest way sometimes are the solutions. The error is not showing, but I can't get the result yet. When I try, it still returns null:
> cr <- corr("specdata", 400)
> head(cr)
NULL

Comment: That probably has more to do with the fact that your function has no return value.