# Loading multiple SQL tables in R

Tags: r, rodbc

I am currently attempting to load multiple SQL tables into R studio using `i`, which is described as chr [1:36] with elements separated by spaces, and I am using the following command:

```
for (i in tables){
  assign(i, sqlQuery(dbconnection, paste("select * from ", i, ";")))
}
```

The goal here is to load SQL tables into R using the table name that is on the SQL Server as the name for the dataframe.

I keep on getting the following error message:

> In assign(i, sqlQuery(dbconnection, paste("select * from ", i, ";"))) :
>       only the first element is used as variable name

And sure enough, only the first SQL table is loaded in my data environment. Would someone be able to help?

Comment: This question looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441628/r-getting-warnings-only-the-first-element-is-used-as-variable-name. What is in tables? Just the table names?

Comment: Can you post what is in tables using the `dput(tables)` command?  Please note that if you created tables using `tables <- sqlTables(dbconnection)` there will be tables which are system tables, so they cannot all be queried.

Comment: Using `assign()` at all is a bad idea. Generally, you should not use `assign()` ever. Create an empty list the same length as the number of tables you want, and fill each element of the list in turn.

Comment: @cgrafe, yes, just table names.

Comment: @KerryJackson, think of it as being table1, all the way to table36 in the following format:
structure(list(Table_Name = c("table1", "table2",...,"table36")), row.names = c(NA,-36L))
The format above is based on the result from dput(tables).

Comment: @joran, well I initially thought of simply using the loop to name the whole thing:
for (i in tables){
  df<-sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from ", i, ";")))
    i<-df    }
or
for (i in tables){
  i<-sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from ", i, ";")))
     }

But the result of that gave me one table (the first table name in i) and my dataframe was named as i (I'm not sure if I'm just writing the i from the loop wrong)

Comment: try `for (i in 1:nrow(tables$TABLE_NAME) ){
  assign(tables$TABLE_NAME[i], sqlQuery(dbconnection, paste("select * from ", tables$TABLE_NAME[i], ";")))
}`

Comment: @KerryJackson, thank you!!! It worked with one small modification. I removed the $TABLE_NAME from nrow(tables), because otherwise it returned NULL.

Comment: I provided a sketch of how to do it in an answer; you'd do best to avoid `assign()` as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Advice helping you use `assign()` should be avoided. It's bad practice that will create code down the road that is difficult to use and maintain.

It is basically always better to use lists.

```
#Creates a named list the length of the number of tables
table_list <- setNames(vector("list",nrow(tables)),tables$TABLE_NAME)

for (i in tables$TABLE_NAME){
  #Put each table in the list, one by one
  table_list[[i]] <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from ", i, ";"))
}
```

Comment: I tried using it but get the following error: Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = sqlQuery(dbconnection, paste("select * from ",  : 
  no such index at level 2

Comment: @Geezerz See my edit; it's challenging to write code that *exactly* matches your situation without a more reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you joran, I was able to do what you told me to, the only difference is that all the tables are bundled under table_list vs. having multiple tables that are separate one from the other.